# How to repeat part of TimelineLite Timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I'm using Greensocks library 'TimelineLite' for tweening.

I've been looking out for a solution to this without any luck. How do I make part of my Timeline of timelineLite. Say I have 10 tweens inside a timeline and I want to make 3-10 to loop infinitely and the first three to loop just one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add an event listener to the tweenLite tween using "onComplete:loop;"

```
var myTimeline:TimelineLite = new TimelineLite({onComplete:loop});
```

you add a label at the point you want to start the loop:

```
//Add a "spin" label 3-seconds into the timeline
myTimeline.addLabel("spin", 3);
```

Then create the loop function

```
function loop():void
{
  //go to the "spin" label and play the timeline from there
  myTimeline.gotoAndPlay("spin");
}
```

EDIT: or without having to create a separate `loop` function:

```
var myTimeline:TimelineLite = new TimelineLite({
    onComplete: tl.gotoAndPlay,
    onCompleteScope: tl,
    onCompleteParams: ["spin"],
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [TimelineMax](http://www.greensock.com/timelinemax/). You can attach child timelines to a TimelineMax. So you can put your looping tweens on one timeline (which is set to repeat) and append that to a parent timeline which also has the non-looping tweens.